# How to include Saturday and Sunday data in Sql query

Tags: sql, odbc

I would like to pull data into my query for JUST the previous day. When I run the query on Monday I would like to have data for Saturday and Sunday as well.

The below part of the query works fine but it does not include Sat and Sun when ran on a Monday. Can anyone give me an idea of what to add?

```
where ([ImportDate] = DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                        WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1 END,    
     DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  But you want to make it a range of dates that would include the previous days you want up to the current date, by using `>=` `<` or a `BETWEEN`.

```
where [ImportDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
and [ImportDate] < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Great thank you WAMLeslie, much appreciated :-)